# Accessing Scala private classes from another module

Tags: scala, maven, pom.xml

I have a Scala/Spark project (built with Maven) in which I want to do the following.

I would like to modify `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendations.ALS`, so I've copied the source code of that file into my own package: `org.apache.spark.mllib.myrecommendations.ALS`. However, it relies on some classes like `org.apache.spark.util.Utils`, which are declared as `private[spark]`.

I had hoped that by putting my code inside of `org.apache.spark`, it would be able to access the private members. But it is complaining, perhaps because Spark is imported via a Maven module? How can I work around this?

Here is how the pom.xml imports spark-mllib:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is an example of an error message I run into:

```
error: variable checkpointDir in class SparkContext cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.SparkContext
[WARNING]         if (sc.checkpointDir.isDefined && (iter % 3 == 0)) {
[WARNING]                ^
```

Looking in the source of org.apache.spark.SparkContext, I see that checkpointDir is declared as private to org.apache.spark:

```
private[spark] var checkpointDir: Option[String] = None
```

Why is it that I can't access this member even though my code is in org.apache.spark.mllib.myrecommendation.ALS, a child of org.apache.spark?

Comment: You should never use private members of any class! Please check if any of that methods/classes that you would like to invoke/create has public interface. Using private members is fundamental error.

Comment: The private members are private for a reason. Attempting to defeat that is a fundamental error as @bkowalikpl said. If you believe the members are incorrectly made private then take that issue up with the Spark software authors.

Comment: You don't seem to have understood my question. I understand that application/client code should not access private members. However, I am attempting to modify the implementation of one of the classes that is *part* of Spark. Since this class is part of Spark itself, it makes sense for it to access classes and methods that are private to the "spark" package. I would like to know if it is possible to add new classes to an existing package from a different Maven project.

Comment: What is the compiler error message you are getting?

Comment: Edited with an example of the error.

Comment: Where does this compile error message you posted occur? I think you indeed should be able to access private[spark] fields from a package org.apache.spark.mllib.myrecommendations.ALS, so something else may be at play here.

Comment: I would think you'd get an error for defining a class that already exists on the classpath...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me.

Since packages are open, adding to them in the way you describe is perfectly fine (modulo loading from sealed jar files).

A trivial sbt project with ALS.scala modified to reside in package `recommendation2` (and fixing a couple of `private[recommendation2]`) and importing `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel`.

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint", "-deprecation")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.2.0",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
)
```

Then

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Set current project to SparkHack (in build file:/home/apm/tmp/spark-hack/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/apm/tmp/spark-hack/}spark-hack...
[info] Resolving [snip]...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/apm/tmp/spark-hack/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 22 s, completed Jan 19, 2015 9:10:03 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not try to violate visibility and accessibility rules, in any programming language. If you really need to change something in Spark source code where it was not designed for, the safe approach is to :

- clone the source code
- apply the modifications
- build and publish in your local Maven repository (changing something in the artifact identifier)
- update your pom.xml to refer to the new version you have created

Spark tests are executed as a part of the build and hopefully if your modifications introduce bugs, you will discover it because a test fail.

Comment: The OP isn't violating visibility, just using internal API. Access rules help manage the risk of doing that.